# How to get multiple named querystring values in jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following parameters

```
/Search?category=1&attributes=169&attributes=172&attributes=174&search=all
```

I'm trying to get **just the attributes** querystring values as an array in javascript, for example.

```
attributes = ['169','172','174']
```

Bearing in mind there may be other parameters that are irrelevant such as search or category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not the proper answer but just tried

```
var str = "/Search?category=1&attributes=169&attributes=172&attributes=174&search=all";

var str1 = str.split("&");
var attributesArray = [];

  for(var i=0; i<str1.length; i++) {
     if (str1[i].includes("attributes")) {
       attributesArray.push(str1[i].replace("attributes=", ""));
     }
}
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5Lkk0gnz/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
(function() {
  
    function getJsonFromUrl(url) {
   var query = url.substr(1);
   var arr = [];
   query.split("&").forEach(function(part) {
     var item = part.split("=");
     arr.push(decodeURIComponent(item[1]));
   });
   return arr;
 }

    var url = "https://example.com?category=1&attributes=169&attributes=172&attributes=174&search=all";  
    var params = getJsonFromUrl(url); 
    console.log(params);
  
})();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Seriously? jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want, assuming you already have your url:

```
var url = "/Search?ategory=1&attributes=169&attributes=172&attributes=174&search=all";

var attrs = url
  .match(/attributes=\d*/g)
  .map(function(attr){
    return Number(attr.replace("attributes=", ""));
  });

console.log(attrs); //=> [169, 172, 174]
```

Comment: It’s probably not a good idea to assume the value of the attributes key will be all digits. Better to match any char up to `(&|$)`, non-greedy. Then, since it’ll be uri encoded, decode it.

Comment: True that, also this minimal code should be enhanced and adapted to OP particular problem, say, by making a function or something